# Is there an application or a method to test the positioning on Android only by wi-fi access points?

Tags: wi-fi, google-maps, geolocation, maps, navigation

I need to test positioning  only by wi-fi access points.But when I turn on geolocation on my Android device the position is calculated by GPS+ GSM + Wi-fi. My device  doesn't   give the option to save it and only determine by the wi-fi networks.

So is there some way or application that will give such an opportunity to use only Wi-Fi  access points for positioning?

Comment: Use an app that only requests permission to get "coarse location", then activate Air Plane mode and reactivate Wifi. Then GPS and mobile network/Bluetooth triangulation is disabled and only Wifi is left to get the position.

Comment: Can it work with Google maps? And do you know  such apps that  only request "coarse location".. can you suggest any?

Comment: Depending on the Android versions and models, there is a Location settings to choose "Location mode". On Nexus 5 (Lineage OS 14.1/Android 7.1.2), it's possible to choose "Battery saving" that only uses Wi-Fi, Bluetooth, and cellular network. On Pixel 3a (Android 11) though, there's only an option to enable Wi-Fi scanning without turning off GPS.

Comment: As you speak of "testing": Would it suffice to see where which location provider does position you? Then take a look at [SatStat](https://f-droid.org/packages/com.vonglasow.michael.satstat/), which can show you the position for each location provider separately (see the 4th and 5th screenshot on the linked page).

Comment: @Izzy I need to test  what geolocation datas are getting our device and approprietly the third party apps

Comment: Isn't that exactly what SatStat shows in those screenshots? Or are you rather asking of testing it directly with your apps?